# MathKernel with `-noprompt` hangs indefinitely when converting simple TeX expression

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp, kernel, scripting

If I enter

```
MathKernel -noprompt -run 'ToExpression["1", TeXForm]; Exit[]'
```

the kernel hangs, apparently while running `TeX.exe` as a `mathlink` (see below).  But when I remove `-noprompt`, it runs just fine.  Similar results hold if I pass these commands (to either `MathKernel` or `MathematicaScript`) as a script.

Alternatively, even with `-noprompt`, any of the other formats accepted by `ToExpression` work just fine.

Any ideas why this happens?

---

Rather than printing the output, I could just write to file and send all the prompt garbage to `/dev/null`, but this really doesn't fit into my tool chain very well.  So I'd appreciate any solutions or workarounds.  I'm running Mathematica 9.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) on OS X 10.6.8.

My evidence for believing that it's `TeX.exe` causing the problem is that my processes look like this

```
2772 s000  S+     0:00.28 /Applications/Local/Mathematica.app/Contents/MacOS/MathKernel -noprompt -run Print[ToExpression["1", TeXForm]];Exit[]
2773 s000  S+     0:00.04 /Applications/Local/Mathematica.app/SystemFiles/Converters/Binaries/MacOSX-x86-64/TeX.exe -ml -mathlink -linkmode connect -linkprotocol SharedMemory -linkname jv5_shm
```

Now, without `-noprompt`, I also see `TeX.exe` in the process list with the exact same arguments.  But it's only there briefly, and it returns normally.  Also, I can run `file TeX.exe`, and see that it is indeed a Mac executable (not Windows, as the name would suggest).

Comment: The name of TeX.exe is the same on all platforms, but it doesn't mean that it's invalid or unused on Mac or Linux.  I can reproduce the problem on OS X 10.8 too.

Comment: A workaround is to put the commands in a text file (`file.m`) and run it using `math -script file.m`